# My dart code does not compile because of some onknown error in line 4

Tags: dart, compiler-errors

Here is my code

```dart
void myFunction() {
  return const Person(
    name: 'John T',
    onAccess: (val) => FirebaseFirestore.instance,//error
  )
}
```

but it is not compiling!!!
what do I do?????

Comment: In the future, it would be easier for people to help you if you include the error message in your question.  Doing so also would allow other people encountering the same problem to find your question by searching.

Comment: I'm new here so I didn't know that but I'll note that down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
void myFunction() {
  return Person(
    name: const 'John T',
    onAccess: (val) => FirebaseFirestore.instance, //functions do not support const constructors
  )
}
```